# How to pass an Function from Parent to Child in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In that I have App.js this is Parent component. And I have

Another component that is Child.js this component is Child for App.js.

I Child.js I have one button for that I have written one function that is when someone clicks the

Button it's background color will change. I have written that in Child.js component and applied

To that Button. Now I have to change Child.js Button Text color, for that I have written one

function in App.js and I am trying to pass that function to Child.js. But I am unable to get

Output so Please help me to get output.

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './Child/Child';

function App() {
  const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState('');

  const changeTextColor = () => {
    setTextColor('yellow')
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child Fun={changeTextColor}></Child>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Child.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Child.css';

const Child = (props) => {
    console.warn(props)
    const [bg, setBg] = useState('')
    const color = () => {
        setBg('red')
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <button className='btn btn-primary'
            style={{background: bg}}
             onClick={() => {color(); props.Fun()}}>Child Button</button>
       </div>
  )
}

export default Child
```

Comment: basically on click of child's button , you need the parents function to be called?

Comment: You're changing the text color but you aren't using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `textColor` state anywhere. My guess is you want to use it this way:

```
const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState('white');

<Child textColor={textColor} Fun={changeTextColor}></Child>
```

and in the child component:

```
    <div>
        <button className='btn btn-primary'
        style={{background: bg, color: props.textColor }}
         onClick={() => {color(); props.Fun()}}>Child Button</button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a prop to the child component regarding the color change. I see in your case, no prop is being sent to the child .

https://codesandbox.io/s/access-child-component-method-react-hook-olmco?file=/src/Child.js:0-445

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

function Parent() {
  const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState("");

  function changeTextColor() {
    setTextColor("blue");
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child Fun={changeTextColor} textColor={textColor} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = props => {
  const [bg, setBg] = useState("");
  const color = () => {
    setBg("red");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary"
        style={{ color: props.textColor, background: bg,  }}
        onClick={() => {
          color();
          props.Fun();
        }}
      >
        Child Button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing down and using your function correctly. If you would log `textColor` in `App.js` you would see that the color did in fact update.

The problem is, you are currently not using your `textColor` variable anywhere so you don't see the change. Pass down `textColor` to your child as wel and use it somewhere to see the change visually.

---

*(Note: In this scenario I'd keep your `textColor` state in your child component instead of the `App`)*